# Iterate once and perform many actions or iterate for every action in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, dom, multidimensional-array

I have a .txt file with a lot of data that I'd like to analyze. It's a long string containing multiple lines with a date, a person and a message, finishing with an end of line. I already managed to get an array of the strings using .split("\n") and created a function  that parses the line into an object with my desired properties.
Now, I need to obtain data like how many messages per person, how many messages in a year, but I only need to do this once, when I load the file.

Should I iterate through the array of objects for each query after parsing?

```
messageByPerson(array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Count the messages
    }
}
```

Or should I create a data structure for each query and update the count when parsing in the main loop?

```
messagesByPerson = [{
    person: 'example',
    count: 23
}, ...]
```

Note that:

The file can be quite big and contain 200k+ lines.
Can not use a remote database to store any data.

Comment: It's up to you, this is probably too opinion-based a question for SO's format. But FWIW, from what you describe, I can't see much of a reason not to go with your *"Or should I create a data structure for each query and update the count when parsing in the main loop?"* approach. (Which means you may not need to keep the individual per-line objects at all.) Repeatedly searching through the array of 200k+ objects seems like unnecessary overhead unless there's a strong reason for it you're not citing.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just new in programming and maybe there was a fancy way to do it. And sorry if it's too opinion based, couldn't find an answer.